# How to get to the next step in the procedure?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic, computer-science

This is from https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse311/14au/slides/lecture12-filled.pdf,

This procedure is used to solve a modular exponentiation problem, say 
[image]

Here is the procedure [image]

How do you get from the first step to the second step?

To get $a^2$ mod m on the left side, I would multiply both sides of the first step by a to get

$a^2$ mod m  $\equiv a^2$ (mod m )

How do i get from that to $(a $mod m$)^2$ mod m?

Comment: to put things in latex you need a $ sign on either side of the expression and the equiv was wrong because you had a forward slash after it...hope my edits helped

Comment: @Gabriel Yeah they did. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use the following lemma. If $x\equiv a \pmod{m}$ and $y\equiv b\pmod{m}$ then $xy\equiv ab\pmod{m}$.  This may already have been proved in your course. If it has not, here is a quick proof. We want to show that $m$ divides$xy-ab$. Note that
$$xy-ab=x(y-b)+b(x-a).$$
Since $m$ divides $y-b$ and $m$ divides $x-a$, the result follows.

We use the above lemma, taking $b=a$ and $x=y=a\bmod{m}$. We get
$$(a\bmod{m})^2\equiv a^2\pmod{m}.$$
Thus the left side and the right side have the same remainder on division by $m$. It follows that
$$(a\bmod{m})^2\bmod{m}=a^2\bmod{m},$$
which is what we wanted to show.

The result about $a^4\bmod{m}$ is proved in the same way.

Comment: Thanks for that explanation. Now I get why we proved that in the first place. Do you know why a mod m $\equiv$a(mod m) for any as though? Is that a property? I am just going to use it for now.

Comment: Divide $a$ by $m$. We get $a=qm+r$ for some $q$ and $r$, with $0\le r\lt m$. The number $r$ is the remainder, often called $a\bmof{m}$ by people in Computer Science. From $a=r+qm$, we conclude that $a\equiv r\pmod{m}$.

Comment: That makes sense. But that's a $\equiv$ r (mod m), not a mod m $\equiv$ a (mod m)

Comment: Sorry, but how did you reach this conclusion - "the left side and the right side have the same remainder on division by m" ?

Comment: The remainder that I called $r$ ((because that is the letter commonly used in Number Theory) is, as I wrote in a comment (with a TeX error) often called $a\bmod{m}$ by people in Computer Science. By definition, $x \bmod{m}$ is the remainder when $x$ is divided by $m$.

Comment: About your left side right side question, $x\equiv y\pmod{m}$ if and only if $x$ and $y$ have the same remainder on division by $m$.  Proof in one direction: If $x=q_1m+r$ and $y=q_2m+r$ (same remainder $r$) then $x-y=q_1m-q_qm$, so $x-y$ is divisible by $m$, and therefore $x\equiv y\pmod{m}$. Proof in the other direction is also not difficult.

Comment: Oh ok that makes more sense. But wouldn't that still be a $\equiv$ a mod m mod(m), and not the other way around?

Comment: In general we have $x\equiv y\pmod{m}$ if and only if $y\equiv x\pmod{m}$. For $m$ divides $x-y$ if and only if $m$ divides $y-x$.

Comment: For your left side right side proof, you can't assume that you have the same remainder at the beginning right? This is how I wold do it. Say x = $q_1$m + $r_1$. y = $q_2$m + $r_2$. Then x - y = m( $q_1$ - $q_2$) + $r_1$ -  $r_2$. That means that $r_1$ -  $r_2$ = km for some integer k. But k has to be zero because 0<= r < m, so  $r_1$ = $r_2$

Comment: For the direction I did it for in the comment, showing that if they have the same remainders, then $\dots$, you can assume it, we are told the remainders are the same. For the other direction (not done in the comment), one proceeds exactly as you did. We let the remainders be $r_1$ and $r_2$, argue that $|r_1-r_2|$ is divisible by $m$, and use size considerations to show $r_1=r_2$.

Comment: Oh because bi-conditional - both directions

Comment: Yes, we are proving a biconditional. The biconditional can be proved all at once, but for clarity it is useful to prove the two parts separately. I did one, you did the other and I confirmed.